# A-frame: play a random sound on click

Tags: audio, random, aframe

I'm making scene with a radio-like object, and I'd like to make it play a random audio file from my assets when is clicked. This question help me a lot to understand how to add the audio files [Play sound on click in A-Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921013/play-sound-on-click-in-a-frame)
but I can't figure out the random aspect. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an array of sound elements

```
// use ID's - grab by document.getElementById(audioIds[num])
var audioIds = ['one', 'two', 'three'] 

// use a class - grab by audioEls[num]
var audioEls = document.getElementsByClassName('sharedClassName')
```

and use a simple random to select an item

```
// get a random number between 0 and the number of the elements
let lastIndex = audioEls.length - 1 // arrays begin at 0.
var audioEl = audioEls[Math.round(Math.random() * lastIndex)]
```

---

Then on `click` stop any playing sound, and grab a new one:

```
this.el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (!playing) {
      audioEl = audio[Math.round(Math.random() * (audio.length - 1))]
      audioEl.play();
    } else {
      audioEl.pause();
      audioEl.currentTime = 0;
    }
    playing = !playing;
});
```

You can check it out in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fq2pqwfx/41/).

Comment: Thank you very much, Piotr!

Comment: Dear Piotr, could it be possible that this solution in ment to handle only two audio assets? I've tried to adjust the values to my scene ("(audio.length - 4)", as I have five audio assets) but the component only plays randomly the first two.Sorry for the noob question and thank you again!

Comment: @MarcosAlfonzo Sorry, i've made a mistake and used some c++ magic with the Random % number. There should be Random * number since js `Math.random` returns a number between [0, 1). I've updated the anwser and the fiddle to have 4 audio elements

Comment: Thank you very much for continuing to think about the problem!

Comment: @MarcosAlfonzo no problem, sorry for the mistake, happy coding :)